# How to change end of filename

Tags: filenames, rename, macos

I am using Mac Terminal and I need to delete end of filename.

Example of filename : `1516092009.M432844P7000.camel5,S=14022,W=14295/2,`

I need to delete the end `/2,` and I tried command:

`rename 's/\/2,//g' *` which I think should work but don't. Not all of files in folder have this end.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: This is not a valid filename.  `1516092009.M432844P7000.camel5,S=14022,W=14295` is a directory and `2,` is the file.

Comment: Not really I have few hundred files and they look like this.

Comment: it's not possible to have a filename with `/` in it.

Comment: These files are generated from linux server and when I open them in Finder browser I can see them like it. If I delete ```/2,``` file is ok. So I guess it can not be directory

Comment: Please show partial output of `ls -alp` for some of these files.

Comment: If you see a file ending `/2,` in the Finder browser, it will end in `:2,` when viewed in Terminal.  cf https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173529/when-did-the-colon-character-become-an-allowed-character-in-the-filesystem.   If you want to rename _in the command line_, you'll need to use the filename as visible in shell.

Comment: Thank you, that is the problem.

Comment: Sorry Jesse_b that I tried to convince you.

Comment: Did you try using the cut command?

Comment: @DominikNovák Please show what the filenames are when viewed in the terminal, e.g. by updating the question and adding the output of `ls -d` for one of the files. Jesse is totally correct in saying that a filename can't contain a `/` character, not on any Unix system. If you see a `/` in a filename, then that is the result of decoding some other combination of characters in a particular application, as  user4556274 suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you list the file in the Finder and just delete the last 2 characters from there. You can select the filename and then change the name.